Gravitational potential due to arbitrary shape
Outside the uniform sphere, the potential is expressed as if all the masses are concentrated in the center of the sphere.
Is it also true for arbitrary shape?
That is, outside any body, is potential expressed as if the body is at the center of gravity point?

For arbitrary shape you need to use the center of mass.

An arbitrary shape always has a center of mass, but the gravitational potential will not be inversely proportional to the distance from it and the gravitational field will not point toward it. To find the potential, you have to integrate over the shape, treating each infinitesimal bit of mass as a point mass.

No. This is characteristic to the sphere only. A more complicated shape will have a completely different potential, and you need to use the gravitational analog of Coulomb's law to compute it.

In short, no. The fact that a spherical mass distribution produces a field that acts as if all the mass were concentrated at the center is a consequence of the spherical geometry and the inverse square nature of the gravitational attraction. In general the gravitational field produced by an arbitrary source will not act as if all the mass were concentrated at a point,i.e. the field has multipole character. However, all distributions of mass posses a centroid or center of mass.
